# mongodb jest error ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I am trying to test basic mongoDB operation using Jest.

```
  it('should insert a record into collection', async () => {
  const users = await db.collection('mariochar');
  const mockUser = { name: 'marioChar3'};
  await users.insertOne(mockUser);

  const insertedUser = await users.findOne({name: 'marioChar3'});
  expect(insertedUser).toEqual(mockUser);
});
```

If I use the default Jest suggested [template](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb) as above, tests are passing correctly and records can also be seen in the database.

However, since I was learning from this youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oYtk83FZCA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jpvoYriLI0bY8DOgWZfi6u&index=6), I tried to test the Schema directly as shown in the video like this:

```
  it('should insert a mario into collection', async () => {
    const MarioCharSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      weight: Number
    })
    const MarioChar = await mongoose.model('mariochar', MarioCharSchema)
    const char = await new MarioChar({ name: "Mario" })
    char.save()
    console.log(char.isNew)
    expect(char.isNew).toBeTruthy()
  });
```

I get the error: `ReferenceError: You are trying to`import`a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.`

After viewing few posts in stackoverflow, I added the fake timer and I am posting the complete code below. It did not get rid of the error.

My second question is that even though Jest shows the above error and also `npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.`, it shows the test as passed. Is there a way to report it as failed instead since it is easy to mistake it as passed when there will be a lot of tests?

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
jest.useFakeTimers()
describe('insert', () => {
 let connection;
 let db;

 beforeAll(async () => {
   jest.useFakeTimers()
   connection = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/testaroo", {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true
   });
   db = await connection.db();
 });

 afterAll(async () => {
   await connection.close();
 });

 it('should insert a mario into collection', async () => {
   const MarioCharSchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     weight: Number
   })
   const MarioChar = await mongoose.model('mariochar', MarioCharSchema)
   const char = await new MarioChar({ name: "Mario" })
   char.save()
   expect(char.isNew).toBeTruthy()
 });
});
```

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  "preset": '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
  "timers": "fake",
  "testEnvironment": "node"
};
```

`package.json`

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.9.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^1.1.5",
    "jest": "^26.0.1"
  }
...
```

full error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at model.Document.$__getAllSubdocs (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2890:37)
      at _getPathsToValidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2159:23)
      at model.Document.$__validate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2314:23)
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:369:33
      at node_modules/@jest/fake-timers/build/legacyFakeTimers.js:496:18
 PASS  test/saving.test.js
```

Comment: Please, provide the whole error, never strip them down. Call stack may suggest where it occurs. From what you posted, it's unclear at which point this import occurs. The only problem I see here is that save isn't awaited, it's asynchronous and should be `await char.save()`. It's also unclear why you need fake timers here, they aren't supposed to do any good if there are processes that are async by design.

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask. Thanks. I added the error text in the above post. If I use await, I get

```
 Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:
```

Comment: There should be `await`, that's the key. And the problem is what the error says, a timeout. Always try to increase a timeout for Jest when you deal with database. But in your specific case the problem is that you connected with Mongo but try to use Mongoose. Mongoose chains connection promise internally. If there's no connection, a promise is pending, awaiting for it will result in a timeout, this is what happened. The solution here is to connect with Mongoose and forget about MongoClient.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask . Works perfectly. Also helped me make sense of what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Had the same issue, adding "timers": "fake", solved it for me.